# How to add dependency between multiple projects in single workspace in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

We have a very big iOS application with multiple features, each feature has their own flow, some feature depends on another feature and a common datasource class to divide between each feature. Since because of this much code project taking lots of time to compile.
Can i divide the project into multiple projects and add into a workspace and compile only those projects in which making change.
I am not able to find how i can create dependency between projects and how can i access files form one project to another.

I don't want to create static library and into another project.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on a project in a similar manner.

I saw this blogpost from hubspot which has some insights on what you are trying to do. It talks about separating the application 'flows' into cocoapods which can be worked on separately.

http://product.hubspot.com/blog/architecting-a-large-ios-app-with-cocoapods

Comment: Thanks. Cocoapods used for download static libraries at runtime. I guess this wouldn't help with mulitproject dependency.